# css box with arrow and shadow

Tags: html, css

I've searched this site and tried using the examples found with other posts but I still can't figure out how to get my arrow on popup box to have a shadow....

I've made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4z9uV/3/

my css:

```
.notesdisplay3 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 175px;
  padding: 19px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px; 
  font-weight: bold;
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg);

}

.notesdisplay3:before { 
bottom: 100%; 
left: 50%; 
border: solid transparent; 
content: ""; 
height: 0; 
width: 0; 
position: absolute; 
border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); 
border-bottom-color: #f5f5f5; 
border-width: 20px; 
margin-left: -20px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually it's impossible to do this since your triangle is a shadow.

### But!

Since your triangle has a 90 degree angle, you could use a rotated square with a shadow :)

I put the rotated square with the shadow in the `:after` part, and to hide the part in the top shadow of the popup box, I used a triangle with no shadow in the `:before` (as you had in the beginning).

---

## Fiddle

```
.notesdisplay3:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 28px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin-left: -28px;
}

.notesdisplay3:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #CCC;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```